# Update existing pages with URL on click image

Tags: javascript

The following images are advertisement banners and I want to add a clickable out link on each image as it displays.

```js
var list = [
  "image1.jpg",
  "image2.jpg",
  "image3.jpg",
  "image4.jpg",
  "image5.jpg",
  "image6.jpg",
  "image7.jpg",
  "image8.jpg",
  "image9.jpg",
  "image10.jpg",
  "image12.jpg",
  "image13.jpg"
];

var index = 0;
function changeImgs() {
  index = index + 1;
  if (index == list.length) index = 0;
  var image = document.getElementById('image1');
  image.src = list[index];
}

setInterval(function() {
  changeImgs()
}, 2000);

window.onload = changeimgs;
```

```html
<center>
  <img id="image1" src="image1.jpg">
</center>
```

Comment: So you want to wrap each image in an `a` tag?

Comment: `changeimgs` is not the same as your function name of `changeImgs`

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, it's changeimgs

Comment: I tried wrapping the image but not getting syntax?

Comment: @garyn Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can put the image inside an `a` (link) tag and update its `href` each time you change the image.

```
<center>
  <a id="imgLink" href="image1.jpg"><img id="image1" src="image1.jpg"></a>
</center>
<script>
function changeImgs() {
  index = index + 1;
  if (index == list.length) index = 0;
  var image = document.getElementById('image1');
  image.src = list[index];
  document.getElementById("imgLink").href = list[index];
}
</script>
```